# Conversion of GPA from scale of 10 to 4 (India)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, gpa

I am an undergraduate student from India, interested in applying for Ph.D. programs in Astronomy in US institutes. My institute evaluates the CGPA from a scale of 10.
Since the cutoff for Astronomy is 3.0 on a scale of 4 for most US Institutes, my question is what would be the minimum on a scale of 10 in India, assuming I dont go by the conversion (3/4)*10=7.5

Comment: A 3.0 is a B. Do you have letter grade conversions?

Comment: yes, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide the official evidence of your results, and perhaps the topics covered in the subjects (such as the syllabi).

Then the university will make their own evaluations based on their knowledge of their own courses and experience.